# Where Refit interfaces fit in a Clean Architecture structure

Tags: c#, clean-architecture

I want to start using [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit), it is a great library, but I'm having some hard time to keep the project structure clean because the library is at the same time the abstraction(interface) and the implementation(just consume it).

Based on either of these templates for clean architecture:
https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture or
https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

Normally these http clients interfaces goes into the core project(domain or application) where the implementation goes into the infrastructure project, but [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) does both.

So where we should place the [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) interfaces to keep the core clean without a reference to the external libraries based on any of the clean architecture templates?

Comment: I had the same question, and finally I decided to no use refit. I think it breaks the independency I want to keep in the Application layer over all external resource.

Answer (score 2):

You've struck on a key issue with attribute-based configuration. It tends to force you to reference your attributes on a level that you would rather keep agnostic.
This is why some developers start favoring a Fluent language model when it is available (over an attribute-based one), specifically to avoid this issue.

If you intend to use Refit, and you intend to properly separate and abstract it, you would need to only reference the library *and its interfaces* in your Infrastructure layer. These interfaces should only be used internally in Infrastructure as they are an implementation detail that should not leak.
You would end up having an additional interface that is exposed publicly. E.g.:

- an `IPersonRepository` interfaces which is used (and defined) outside of Infrastructure
- an `IMyProviderClient` which is your Refit interface, which lives in Infrastructure.
- A `PersonRepository` class which implements `IPersonRepository`, lives in Infrastructure, and has a `IMyProviderClient` dependency injected into it.

*The key goal here is that with the above approach, you can isolate Refit so that it only needs to be referenced in your Infrastructure project, and nowhere else in your codebase. That's the goal here.*

If you think this is too much of a hassle, then either you're not thinking cleanly enough or you've proven to yourself that the Refit way of working is too incompatible with a simpler clean approach.

It all depends on how much you want to use Refit.

To be perfectly honest, I often don't leak my http clients outside of Infrastructure anyway, so Refit wouldn't really incur and additional cost that I otherwise would not be paying anyway.